# How to get the count of likes from a Twitter post using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, selenium4, relative-locators

I'm trying to find a way to get the likes counter from any given Twitter post.

For example, this tweet: https://twitter.com/whale_alert/status/1508925640745140232

I have tried using every element around that text with no success.

What should I call on to get the like counter from tweets?

Comment: Please post the code trial what you have done so far to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 3):

The element with number of likes is left to the element with text as *`Likes`*.

To extract the number of likes you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the [relative `Left of`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#left-of) locator strategy:

- Using *XPATH* and [`RelativeBy(object)`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/da84700804d4381fe3049b8af78d2f211d08f0fc/py/selenium/webdriver/support/relative_locator.py#L58):

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get('https://twitter.com/whale_alert/status/1508925640745140232')
  likes = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Likes']")))
  likes_count = driver.find_element(locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, "span").to_left_of(likes))
  print(likes_count.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  87
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[Selenium 4 - Relative Locators](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-4-relative-locators)