# How to use locate_with in selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4, relative-locators

I'm trying to use [relative locators](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/) in selenium 4, but I'm not having much luck with it.

I found an example [here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-4-relative-locators), but even though I'm able to find the first element, the second line doesn't work and it seems to be stuck there (I cannot close the browser automatically afterwards).

```
decision_div = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "decisions")
conclusion_div = browser.find_element(locate_with(By.TAG_NAME,  "div").below(decision_div))
```

How can I get it to find the next div right below the one with the specified class name?

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you are working on? Otherwise this question is missing basic details

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML

Comment: Update the question with the snapshot of both the relevent elemets.

Comment: @kisalisa https://www.oyez.org/cases/2019/18-1323

Answer (score 1):

As you are able to find the first element, I don't see any issues in your code as such:

```
decision_div = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "decisions")
conclusion_div = browser.find_element(locate_with(By.TAG_NAME,  "div").below(decision_div))
```

You just need to ensure that the the element with the value of *class* attribute as *`decisions`* is above the desired ***`<div>`*** element as follows:

```
<sometagname class="decisions" ...></div>
<div class="some class" ...></div>
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to get the count of likes from a Twitter post using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71669897/7429447)

Comment: Should I use near instead? As you can see from my screenshot, there are nested divs, but the one I want is inmediately below at the same hierarchy level.

Comment: I would suggest you to raise a new question with your updated requirement as _`locate_with`_ doesn't fits your updated usecase. There are much better ways to deal with nested divs.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 4 [relative locators](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/) are dealing with pair of web elements with the similar size and adjacent positions, not what you are trying to do here.
In this case the `div` element you are trying to locate is similarly nested below the parent element located by `decisions` class name.
So, you can simply locate the `conclusion_div` element with this code line:

```py
conclusion_div = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='decisions']//div")
```

But since the locator above gives 13 matches and I don't know which of them you want to locate it could be:

```py
conclusion_div = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='decisions']//div")
```

Or maybe

```py
conclusion_div = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='decisions']//div[contains(@class,'carousel')]")
```

Or maybe

```py
conclusion_div = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='decisions']//div[@class='decision-image']")
```